# Is it safe to call QImage::save() before QPainter::end()

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qimage

In this code:

```
QPainter painter(&image);

// do painting .......

painter.end(); // is this needed?
image.save(tempFileName);
```

do I need to close the QPainter before saving the QImage, in order to flush all changes, or can I save it before closing the QPainter object?

Comment: i think it is a good idea to save only after `painter.end()`. The doc doesn't specifies exactly which resources are release with a call to `end()`. It also seems more logical to write the image only when you are done with it, unless you want to do otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should call `painter.end()` prior to calling `image.save()`.  The behavior of `painter.end()` ultimately depends on the underlying paint engine used on whatever platform your program is running on.  You may be able to get away with calling `image.save()` before `painter.end()` on *some* platforms with *some* versions of Qt, but changing either your platform or your version of Qt could cause you problems later on.